# Update ListView's data

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I used to create a custom adapter which is based upon **BaseAdapter** class, not **ArrayAdapter**.
But here is an issue, when I try to populate my adapter with new data(whatever it is), my **AdapterView** represents more items, than it supposed to have.

Suppose we have an Activity, ListFragment and custom Adapter.

Implementation of an Adapter:

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Entry<String,String>> mDataModel;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private boolean[] isChecked;
private int mResourceId;

private static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView adapterText;
    private TextView adapterDate;
}

public ContactAdapter(Context context,int mResourceId) {
    this(context, mResourceId,new ArrayList<Entry<String,String>>());
}

public ContactAdapter(Context context, int mResourceId,List<Entry<String,String>> mDataModel) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mResourceId = mResourceId;
    this.mDataModel = mDataModel;
    this.isChecked = new boolean[mDataModel.size()];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataModel.size();
}

@Override
public Entry<String,String> getItem(int position) {
    return mDataModel.get(position);
}

public void selectItem(int position) {
    isChecked[position] = !isChecked[position];
}

public void add(final Entry<String,String> entry) {
    mDataModel.add(entry);
    if(mDataModel.size()>isChecked.length) {
        isChecked = Arrays.copyOf(isChecked, isChecked.length / 2 +
                mDataModel.size());
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void unCheckItems() {
    for (int index = 0; index < mDataModel.size(); index++)
        isChecked[index] = false;
}

public void removeItem() {

    for(int index=0;index<mDataModel.size();index++) {
        if (isChecked[index])
            mDataModel.remove(index);
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mDataModel.get(position).hashCode();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parentGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null) {
        convertView=mInflater.inflate(mResourceId,parentGroup,false);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.adapterDate=(TextView)(convertView.findViewById(R.id.adapterDate));
        holder.adapterText=(TextView)(convertView.findViewById(R.id.adapterText));
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)(convertView.getTag());
    holder.adapterDate.setText(mDataModel.get(position).getValue());
    holder.adapterText.setText(mDataModel.get(position).getKey());
    convertView.setSelected(isChecked[position]);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Also I have a usual **ListFragment**'s implementation with additional method addTo(...), in order to add rows to **ListView**.Data comes from an Activity.

Here is the method, which I call within an Activity to send a data to **ListFragment**:

```
    public void addToContact(View view) {
         String contact = mContact.getText().toString();
         if(!contact.isEmpty()) {
              if (contactFragment == null) {
                 contactFragment = (ContactFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(BundleKey.CONTACT_FRAGMENT);
              }
          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          final Entry<String, String> entry = new Entry<>(contact,
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/"
                        + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
           contactFragment.addEntry(entry);

         }

        mContact.getText().clear();
        Toast.makeText(this,(contact.isEmpty()?
            "Enter contact":"Contact has been added"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

So, when I add any new item, my ListView shows two similar items instead of one.Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: `addToContact` is being called twice? You can add a `Log` statement to test that

Comment: Or you need to show us the implementation of `contactFragment.addEntry`

Comment: it's like: `adapter.add(entry)`